# How to forward X through two SSH tunnels?

Tags: ssh, xorg, arch-linux, tunnel, openbsd

I'm trying to run an X program on my home computer from my work computer. The basic setup is this:

Arch Linux work computer -> OpenBSD SSH router(at home) -> Arch Linux home computer(with SSH)

I've never actually tried to do this and I'm not quite sure how to. How would I get this to work?

When I just try doing

```
$(work computer) ssh -Y home-ip
..
$(home router) ssh -Y private-ip
```

I get on the last tunnel "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0"

How do I do this properly?

EDIT: I forgot to enable X forwarding on the sshd of my home computer. I've fixed that now, but nothing seems to happen when I do a simple command like `xterm`. It just sits there, presumably trying to display the xterm window on my router and not on my work computer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about forwarding a port on your work computer to your home computer's port 22 and then `ssh -Y` to that local port?

For example,

```
ssh -L 2222:private-ip:22 router-ip
ssh -Y localhost:2222
```

Comment: Hmm.. Creative! That works for me :)

Answer (score 2):

What you've done should work, but you need to have the `xauth` program installed on the router so that it can create a security key for the virtual X11 display that SSH creates.  You need `xauth` on any machine that you `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` to, even if you don't actually run any X applications there, but just use it as a step toward somewhere else.

After you've connected to the home computer, check your `$DISPLAY` variable.  It should be something like `localhost:10`.  If not, go back to your shell on the router and check `$DISPLAY` there.

Comment: Not *from*, but *to*. The `ssh` client doesn't need to modify xauth data in any way. The *server* needs to create a temporary .Xauthority file.